# Trigger Azure pipeline with multiple repos with in the project

Tags: azure-devops-server-2020

```
 trigger:
 - master

 pool:
   name: 'MobileApps'

 variables:
 - group: Signing

 resources:
   repositories:
    - repository: Commontest
      ref: Signing
      type: git
      name: Common_Test
      trigger:
       branches:
          include:
            - Signing
            - master
       
 steps:

 - checkout: self
 - checkout: Commontest

 - script: echo Hello, world!
   displayName: 'Run a one-line script'

 - script: echo $(branchname)
   displayName: 'branchname'

 - script: |
       echo $(Build.Repository.Name)
       echo $(Build.SourceBranch)
```

I need to trigger the pipeline if other (Commontest) repo have changes in the specific branches.
-Azure-DevOps-Server-2020

When I created a commit on the branch, the trigger does not fire. Both repositories are in the same project Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

```
resources:
   repositories:
    - repository: Commontest
      ref: Signing
      type: git
      name: Common_Test
      trigger:
       branches:
          include:
            - Signing
            - master
```

it's working on Azure DevOps Server 2022.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).